# Powershell to uninstall SCCM 2007 Client remotely

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I use the below command using cmd to uninstall the SCCM client 2007 from a machine manually.

C:\Windows\ccmsetup{4CD82FBB-xxxx-...}
msiexec /x client.msi

What i need to do is,

- This is for 100 machines remotely
- Uninstall the SCCM 2007 client from the same folder mentioned above remotely for 100 machines
- Once the uninstallation of this client is completed
- Install SCCM 2012 client from C:\Windows\ccmsetup2012\ccmsetup.exe from the same machines

Can this be done with powershel ? for remote machines..i have admin access to all the machines that i am targeting.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this from your 2012 console.